# SIMPLE jQuery required validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I have this textbox and button

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Category" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

How can I write a very simple jQuery method when btnAdd is clicked it checks if lblName is empty, if it is empty is just displays a red * after the textbox.

Comment: What research have you done on the topic?

Comment: could not really understand how to display the * part and I do not want to use plugins.

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {

Comment: Where is the beginning part of your `<asp:Label>`?

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As label is render as span so you will have to take the html() function of jQuery as follows

```
 $('lblName').html()
```

Create a function and call it on the onclient click.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Category" 
    OnClientClick="return Check();" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

and jQuery function as follows

```
 function check()
 {
     if($("#lblName").html()=="")
     {
         alert("your message");
         return false;
     }
     else
        return true;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am kinda guessing at what you want your outlook to be, hopefully I got it close.

I would recommend creating a label that sits beside the text box like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Category" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

Then use the function here to check and fill with the `*` if needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnAdd_Click()
    {
        if($("#txtName").val()=="")
        {
            //Textbox is empty
            $("#ErrorLabel").val("*");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#ErrorLabel").val("");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And some simple CSS to color it:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ErrorLabel {color:red;}
</style>
```

Comment: What is the behavior that it is exhibiting? Or is it just not doing anything at all? Have you tried the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313336/simple-jquery-required-validation/14313417#answer-14313348)?

Comment: AHH.... Maybe this.... I forgot to include the "#" in the jQuery methods... Check the updated answer

Comment: still nothing. also added return true and return false to your asnwer and onClientClick instead of onClick=

Comment: hmmm... I haven't used asp.net in a long time. Switched to php and been there ever since.